# Pyodbc: Login timeout expired

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, pyodbc

I am trying to connect to MS SQL Server using pyodbc on local system and on connect to instance i get error:

```
[2020-06-21 15:39:04.110750]: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]SQL Server Network Interfaces: Error Locating Server/Instance Specified [xFFFFFFFF].  (-1) (SQLDriverConnect); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online. (-1)')
```

My SQL Server is Express 2005 and try with drivers:

- {ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server}
- {ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}
- {SQL Native Client}

I test in sqlcmd with this command:

```
C:\Users\Moein>sqlcmd -S '.\Moein' -U 'sa' -P 'xxxx'
HResult 0xFFFFFFFF, Level 16, State 1
SQL Network Interfaces: Error Locating Server/Instance Specified [xFFFFFFFF].
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL Native Client : An error has occurred while establishing a connection to the server. When connecting to SQL Server 2005, this failure may be caused by the fact that under the default settings SQL Server does not allow remote connections..
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL Native Client : Login timeout expired.
```

My Code :

```
import pyodbc

conn = pyodbc.connect(f'DRIVER={SQL Native Client};SERVER=.\Moein;DATABASE=Moein;UID=sa;PWD=xxxx',autocommit=True)
cursor = conn.cursor()
```

**More:**

- Test `-l 600` switch for login timeout more in sqlcmd > not answer recived
- Test `computername\instance` and `127.0.0.1\instance` > Not changed
- Try full reinstall sql server on local > noting changed things

Comment: SQL Server 2005, 2008 and 2008 R2 are all out of even extended support - don't use them anymore! Upgrade to a more recent version ASAP!

Comment: Upgrading Express is free too, there's no excuse to be using technology that has been unsupported for 5+ years.

Comment: @marc_s other software work with sql server work and can login to specific instance !!!

Comment: @Larnu i don't know why not work it , other software can login to sql server without problem

Comment: Neither of those comments tell us why you're using software that has been **completely** unsupported for 5 years though.

Comment: You say that "other software can login". You've shown us that your Python script cannot and sqlcmd cannot, so what "other software" can? Can you create a working DSN in ODBC Administrator (odbcad32.exe)? ...perhaps using the ancient (but more age-appropriate) "SQL Server" ODBC driver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found my problem

i use this connection string with pipe mode:

```
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};ServerName=Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;SERVER=.\testsv;DATABASE=test;Persist Security Info=False;UID=sa;PWD=xxxxx;Data Source=np:\\.\pipe\MSSQL$testsv\sql\query',autocommit=True)
```